# Eigenvalues of Overlapping block diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I look for eigenvalues of general overlapping block diagonal matrices. e.g.

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 3 & 8 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
Where the blocks are overlapping.

$$ \mathbf{A} = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{A}_1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_2 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

In which the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}_1$ and $\mathbf{A}_2$ is already given. 
Is there a way that one can calculate the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ given those conditions? We know $\mathbf{A}_1$ and $\mathbf{A}_2$ are Hermitian.

I thought of perturbation theory to model it as a block diagonal plus a perturbation matrix added as error...
thanks

Comment: [This paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0609004) seems to be relevant since the overlapping entries can be expressed as a low-rank (in this case 2) modification of a Hermitian matrix with a given eigendecomposition.